# Issue following AWS elastic beanstalk flask virtual enviorment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, virtualenv, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to follow the instruction [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html) and have issues with step one:

> Create a virtual environment named eb-virt:
>
> ~$ virtualenv ~/eb-virt

```
dyn-160-39-133-189:~ me$ cd ~
dyn-160-39-133-189:~ me$ virtualenv ~/eb-virt
Using base prefix '/Users/me/anaconda'
New python executable in /Users/me/eb-virt/bin/python
ERROR: The executable /Users/me/eb-virt/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/me' (should be '/Users/me/eb-virt')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

I saw that the anaconda package is being used:

```
which python
/Users/me/anaconda/bin/python
```

Which might be the issue so I tried:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

which gave me both:

```
python -V
-bash: /usr/local/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory
```

and

```
which python
/Users/me/anaconda/bin/python
```

I usually use conda (new to python but it seems to work well) so I'm not sure if the issue lies with conda or something else.

Comment: What is the OS you're using? It looks like it is something out of the ELB standard stack.

Comment: @IgorT. OS X El Capitan (Mac)

Comment: which one is used on AWS?